# Issues with apt-get and dpkg related to Secure Boot

Tags: dpkg, python3, secure-boot

I've recently been having trouble with Ubuntu. Whenever I try to `sudo apt get` something (in this case python 3), I get the error message: `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem`

So I enter the command and after a long process I get this message:

```
Configuring Secure Boot ├────────────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                                   
 │                                                                             
 │ UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with             
 │ third-party drivers.                                                        
 │                                                                             
 │ The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. To permit       
 │ the use of third-party drivers, a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been      
 │ generated. This key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware.     
 │                                                                             
 │ To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user,      
 │ and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then confirm     
 │ the change after reboot using the same password, in both the "Enroll        
 │ MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus that will be presented to you     
 │ when this system reboots.                  
If you proceed but do not confirm the password upon reboot, Ubuntu will     
 │ still be able to boot on your system but any hardware that requires         
 │ third-party drivers to work correctly may not be usable.                    
 │                                                                             
 │                                  <Ok>
```

I am honestly stumped concerning overcoming this.  I need help as to what I can do.

Comment: If there's no reason for having Secure Boot enabled (e.g. dual-booting with Windows 11) then just DISABLE it.

Comment: Make sure that you provide each problematic command exactly and the entire unredacted output of each command. Give us the whole commands exactly as you enter them, not partial commands. Otherwise how can we tell if you're doing everything correctly? For example `sudo apt get python 3` as you wrote it here would be completely incorrect. Also don't post bits and pieces of curated output because you are probably leaving out important diagnostic information.  Copy paste the whole thing.  We can handle it 

Comment: Also, bad idea to mess around with the installed python version. Many parts of Ubuntu rely on a specific python version. Changing this can destroy your system. If you need a specific python version for some task, you should do so in a container or VM or other isolated environment

Comment: @Nmath turns out my problem just got a bit more complicated,turns out i did have python installed,i thought i didn't have it because i was running `python --version` not `python3 --version` and it didn't recognize tkinter in syntax,turns out i have both python and tkinter installed,yet when i import `from tkinter import *` it still doesn't recognize tkinter syntax.Also,do you want me to copy paste the output when i enter the commands?Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nmath turns out i have a fix for this too,turns out it was because i had named my file "tkinter.py",i wish i was joking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `OK`. Then, you will be prompted to set a password. Set a simple password, then the command will complete. Simply type `sudo reboot`, which will reboot your laptop. In the process of rebooting, you will see a blue screen with an option that reads `Enroll MOK`. Click enter on it and type the password that you set. Do the same for the option `Change Secure Boot state`. Then, continue. Your computer will reboot as normal. This is a normal procedure to prevent malware and **not** a bug.

Comment: The thing is,i can't select <Ok>,when i click it it just highlights it,when i press enter nothing happens.

Comment: Press `tab`, then `enter`.